# Text interface for employee management in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust

I'm in the process of reading The Rust Programming Language, and decided to do the 3rd task at the end of the 8th chapter.
The description is as follows:

> Using a hash map and vectors, create a text interface to allow a user to add employee names to a department in a company. For example, “Add Sally to Engineering” or “Add Amir to Sales.” Then let the user retrieve a list of all people in a department or all people in the company by department, sorted alphabetically.

Please tell me if my code is any good.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

use regex::Regex;


fn main() {
    let add_regex = Regex::new(r"^(?i)Add\s(\w(?:\w|\s)*\w?)\sto\s(\w+)$").unwrap();
    let list_regex = Regex::new(r"^(?i)List\s(\w+)$").unwrap();
    let all_regex = Regex::new(r"^(?i)Show all$").unwrap();
    let mut departments: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        let mut input = String::new();

        print!("Enter command: ");
        io::stdout().flush();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input);

        input = String::from(input.trim());

        let add_match = add_regex.captures(&input);
        let list_match = list_regex.captures(&input);
        let all_match = all_regex.captures(&input);

        if add_match.is_some() {
            let unwrapped_match = add_match.unwrap();
            let employee = &unwrapped_match[1];
            let dpt = &unwrapped_match[2];

            match departments.get_mut(dpt) {
                Some(v) => {
                    v.push(String::from(employee));
                    v.sort();
                },
                None => {
                    let emp_list = vec![String::from(employee)];
                    departments.insert(String::from(dpt), emp_list);
                }
            }
        } else if list_match.is_some() {
            let unwrapped_match = list_match.unwrap();
            let employees = departments.get(&unwrapped_match[1]);

            if !employees.is_some() {
                println!("No such department");
                continue;
            }

            println!("Department employees: {}", employees.unwrap().join(", "));
            io::stdout().flush();
        } else if all_match.is_some() {
            for (dpt, employees) in &departments {
                println!("{}: {}", dpt, employees.join(", "));
            }
        } else {
            println!("Please enter a valid command");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Enter command: add f to ff
Enter command: add b to ff
Enter command: list ff
Department employees: b, f
Enter command: add Darth Vader to ff
Enter command: list ff
Department employees: Darth Vader, b, f
Enter command: add d to zz
Enter command: add 1 to zz
Enter command: show all
ff: Darth Vader, b, f
zz: 1, d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance: that function is way too long and deeply nested. Three levels of loop/branch nesting is, in my experience, the most that any function should have; and the more nested it is the shorter it should be.

Consider extracting branch and loop bodies to separate named functions.

---

Your code structure also seems to be “determine what command to execute” (add / list / etc), then “execute said command”. I’d make this explicit, have the regexp parsing of an input line in a separate function that returns the command type and parameters. Dispatching this would be a natural use for `match` over your own Command type. (That said, in a realistic CLI you might need the commands available to be extensible so don’t get too married to this pattern. I’m guessing you’ll get to dynamic polymorphism later in the book.)